# It's possible to log the binding failures?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8.5

I want to know if it's possible to log the requests that hit a server with a host header different than the bindings that I have configured in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always have a catch-all site with these bindings:

```
http *:80:
https *:443:
```

all other sites have bindings to specific host headers or IP addresses.

All the requests that are logged for this catch-all site are of the type you are interested in. There should be no legitimate traffic to this site. It's always interesting to look at the http logs for this site.